# How can I quickly determine what ip range a regular expression evaluates to

Tags: regex, ip, expression, range

I've been given a regular expression that looks for a range of IP addresses. I could sit down and manually determine what IP range it searches for but I was wondering if there is a tool that will do this for me. I've found lots of tools to do the opposite (take an ip range and convert it to a regular expression).

Here's an example regular expression: ^192.22.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])).([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$

What range does this apply to and whats the quickest/easiest way to get it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, there is no way to generate all strings which match an arbitrary regular expression. I doubt anybody wrote a specialized tool for your case, either.

Anyway, your example is simple and idiomatic; it looks for two dotted octet values which are one digit, or two digits, or three digits beginning with 1, or three digits beginning with 2 followed by a digit less than five, or 25 followed by a digit less than six; in other words, 0-255. So the range is 192.22.0.0-192.22.255.255 (192.22.0.0/16).

Comment: Thanks, I agree that this is fairly easy to figure out. I have clients that may not agree however and I was hoping to provide them with a quick go to solution. 

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The web tool [Regexplained](http://tinyurl.com/pba8od7) might help you understand the regex a bit better!

As [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) has mentioned, the regex captures the IP range 192.22.0.0 to 192.22.255.255

However, because the period (.) has not been escaped, it also mistakenly captures a string like:

```
192.22.255
```

The regex should be corrected with backslashes to:

```
^192\.22\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yeah I understand regex well enough I could figure this out. My teammates/clients may not however and wanted to provide a simple solution.

Comment: @mpls423 have you tried out the Regexplained link I put? I was having trouble figuring out your regex until I plugged it into the web tool there.

Comment: Yeah I did, thanks for the link. However my issue again is not so much that I need help understanding it but rather I need a solution that my clients will understand. While the website is helpful for you or me,  it would be intimidating for my clients. Thanks again though.